# Dividing an array of N elements into a matrix in a discontinuous manner

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix

Given an array of `N` elements, where `N` is a multiple of `9`, the array should be divided into a matrix of width `W`, where `W` is a multiple of `3`, and height `H` where `H` is also a multiple of `3`, for example:

The array of 54 members:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 ... 54.
```

The matrix of width 9 and height 6:

```
 1,  2,  3,  10, 11, 12,  19, 20, 21,
 4,  5,  6,  13, 14, 15,  22, 23, 24,
 7,  8,  9,  16, 17, 18,  25, 26, 27,
28, 29, 30,  37, 38, 39,  46, 47, 48,
31, 32, 33,  40, 41, 42,  49, 50, 51,
34, 35, 36,  43, 44, 45,  52, 53, 54,
```

Note that the matrix is built from `3x3` units, so the first 9 members are in the rectangle: `0,0,3,3` and the next 9 members are in the rectangle: `3,0,3,3`, and so on.

How can this array be entered into such a matrix?

```
var arr = new[] {1,2,3 ...};
var mat = new int[arr.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    var matIndex = ?
    mat[matIndex] = arr[i];
}
```

Comment: The prime factors of your number will be of the form `a*3^n (n>=2)`. Your dimentions will be `(3a) by (3^n-1)`

Answer (score 1):

This is a brute force approach I have thought on top of my head.

```
var matrix = new int[6, 9];
var arr = Enumerable.Range(1, matrix.Length).ToArray();

for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0) / 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1) / 3; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
        {
            for (int l = 0; l < 3; l++)
            {
                matrix[3 * i + k, 3 * j + l] = arr[9 * (matrix.GetLength(1) / 3) * i + 9 * j + 3 * k + l];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main idea is that I split the matrix into 3x3 cells (`i` and `j` index) after that, we just populate it based on the shift in the main array.

Comment: If you switch between columns and rows `matrix = new int[9, 6]` there is an `IndexOutOfRangeException` error.

Comment: @googledev it's fixed not. Actually shift by row depends on width.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Community Toolkit has a Type [`Span2D<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/high-performance/span2d), that can wrap 1D-arrays as well as 2D-arrays. So you can copy the array one 3x3 block at a time.

```
int[] arr = {1, 2, ... 54}
int[,] mat = new int[6, 9];
var aSpan = new Span2D<int>(a, height: 18, width: 3);
var mSpan = new Span2D<int>(m);

for (int i = 0; i < aSpan.Height; i += 3) {
    var source = aSpan[i..(i+3), 0..3];
    var destination = mSpan[(i/9*3)..(i/9*3+3), (i%9)..(i%9+3)];
    source.CopyTo(destination);
}
```